# Why is long-term relative frequency used to predict the probability of the event occuring in a single trial?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition

I am a beginner statistics student learning probability from a frequentist perspective. I am confused on the application of a 'probability' to the real world.

Probability is the relative frequency of an event, performed over a **very large** (theoretically, infite) trials. My question: how is this useful when trying to predict the outcome of the random process in a **single trial**?

For example, having a dice land on one has a probability of $\frac 16$. That's fine if we want to predict the chance of landing a one over a **large number of dice rolls**, but it's not accurate for predicting the outcome of the dice roll in a **single roll**.

So my question is what is the rationale of using long-term relative frequency for the chance of a single repetition of the experiment to predict an event? Is it just the 'best guess' we have?

I know logically it may just be the 'best guess' we have, but intuitively it's not clicking for me. An intuitive explanation would help with as much minimal math language as possible!

Edit: To clarify, this is my confusion. The relative frequency of landing on a one in (for example) 6 rolls of the dice is NOT equal to 1/6 nor does it have to come near 1/6. It only comes close to 1/6 after a large number of trials.

So my question is in one trial/roll of the dice why is 1/6 the best prediction we have for estimating the probability of landing a 1? Is it because the long-term relative frequency is about the best guess we have for the outcome of any single trial? Is there more to this than it just being the best guess?

Comment: Why do you say, "having a dice (sic) land on one has a probability of $\frac 16$ ... (is) not accurate for predicting the outcome of the dice (sic) roll in a **single roll**?"  The die has six sides and if the die is fair (i.e. equally weighted) then the chance for each side to come up will be the same.  Are you thinking of the probability after the die has been rolled?  Because that will always be 100% once you know of the outcome.  Have you studied samples from a population, confidence intervals of the true population mean based on samples, and the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson Thank you for your comment. I have unfortunately not gone beyond basic probability theory, although I do have informal knowledge of the three examples you mentioned.

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson To clarify myself again, I have posted my question with an additional edit. I am thinking of the probability before the roll. Snoop has also provided a very detailed mathematical answer (one that i can't understand), but hopefully it sheds some further light on my question.

Comment: Think of a casino.  They pay $600 if you roll a 1.  How much should this game cost you to play for the casino to break even?  Now load a profit margin. Then, does the casino care if only one person plays this game, not hundreds ... everyone else decides to play blackjack and slots?  No, they do not need the long term outcome.  The casino can mix this game with all the others and price it for the chance of one roll.  If you play it once and roll a 1, they are going to make up for their loss on blackjack and slots.  How's that example for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(p)$, assume $p$ not known. If we have IID samples $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ and $N_1$ the total count  of successes then the 'most likely' (maximum likelihood) $p$ is given by the argument maximizing the joint probability of the outcomes (they are IID so you just multiply the pmfs):
$$p_n^*=\max_{p \in [0,1]}\prod_{k=1}^n(p\mathbb{I}_{\{1\}}(X_k)+(1-p)\mathbb{I}_{\{0\}}(X_k))=\max_{p\in [0,1]}p^{N_1}(1-p)^{n-N_1}$$
If $0<N_1<n$ we set the derivative to $0$
$$\frac{d}{dp}p^{N_1}(1-p)^{n-N_1}=\frac{(1-p)^{n-N_1}p^{N_1-1}(np-N_1)}{p-1}=0$$
$$\implies p^*_n=\frac{N_1}{n}$$
otherwise $p^*=0$ if $N_1=0$ and $p^*=1$ if $N_1=n$. This is the relative frequency of successes in our sample. Now we have for example
$$E[p^*_n]=\frac{np}{n}=p$$
$$P(|p^*_n-p|>\varepsilon)\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}E[|p^*_n-p|^2]=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\textrm{Var}[p^*_n]=\frac{p(1-p)}{\varepsilon^2n}\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$$
So it has desirable properties and we use $p^*_n$ to estimate $p$ in frequentist stats. In other words $p^*$ is not the probability $p$ per se but the probability of $|p^*_n-p|$ being greater than arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ goes to $0$ in the limit $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time @Snoop to write up such a detailed response! Unfortunately though as I mentioned I am still a beginner still only learning basic probability theory. Is there any way you could mention the gist of your explanation in non mathematical terms? Thank you very much.

Comment: We use the estimate of the probability of an event over a large number of rolls (i.e. the relative frequency) to estimate the probability over a single roll because such estimate has good properties in the long run, namely it's on average equal to the real probability of success over a single roll and for very large samples the probability of such estimate being significantly different from the real probability is very small. @GildedCrowEscapee

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Having a fair die (i.e. equally weighted on all sides) land on "one" has a probability of $\frac16$. That's fine if we want to predict the chance of landing a "one" over a large number of dice rolls, and it's also accurate for predicting the outcome of the die roll in a single roll.  Probability can be defined as the chance of the stated outcome divided by the total number of possible outcomes. The probability of a fair die landing on an even number is $\frac36 = \frac12$ since there are three even numbers on a total of six sides.  The chance of flipping heads on a fair coin is $\frac12$ since there are two sides and only one is heads.  The frequencies of observed observations represent the sample outcome which may not be equal to the underlying population outcome.